# how can I align to middle by height

Tags: html, css, background-image, vertical-alignment

I want to create image box(with image).
It's ugly when text is in the top of box.

How can I align text to middle?
I tried to use `vertical-align`, but it seems, that it don't works

[Demo of my code](http://jsfiddle.net/DhHnZ/)

**EDIT:**
Your solution works fine with short messages.
But if they will be multi-lined, it is ugly again.
Is it possible to not increase size of line If we don't need it?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What usually works fine is `line-height`:

```
line-height: 32px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DhHnZ/2/

Comment: Works fine with 1-line messages. But is it possible to not increase its size if it will multilined? Example: jsfiddle.net/mRbgq

Comment: If you expect multiple lines, I would recommend using `padding-top: 8px; padding-bottom: 8px;` instead of the line-height thing. (font-size: 16px + 8px above + 8px below = 32px total height)

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/mRbgq/2/

Answer (score 8):

If you want to middle align a block with multiple lines, you can use `display:inline-block` around that block. So if you have:

```
<div class="messageInfo">
   <div class="messageInner">You are logged out<br>You are crazy<br> gogo</div>
</div>
```

with

```
.messageInfo{
    background: lightskyblue;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6lkS.png) ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height: 32px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left:32px;
    line-height:32px;
}
```

add

```
.messageInner {
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:1.2em;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/yNpRE/1/ and http://jsfiddle.net/yNpRE/

Be warned though, that while this works in modern browsers, it doesn't work with IE7 or earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Set the `line-height` to the `height` of the `div`.

So

```
.messageInfo{
    background: lightskyblue;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6lkS.png) ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height: 32px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left:32px;
    line-height:32px; //ADD THIS
}
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/DhHnZ/1/

Comment: Works fine with 1-line messages. But is it possible to not increase its size if it will multilined? Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mRbgq/