# Vertical Centering the Text

Tags: html, css

I am unable to set my text as vertical-center. My text is placed in position:absolute div.

```
<div class="mydiv">Frameworks and Extensions</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.mydiv{
    width:100px;
    height:70px;
    border:1px solid red;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#ccc;    
}
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3Zv5s

Sometimes Text will come two or one line. The text should be in vertical center like in table td.

Thanks for your valuable time and suggestion.

Comment: Like this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616969/center-text-vertically-within-div

Answer (score 2):

Try with this CSS:

```
.mydiv{
    width:100px;
    height:70px;
    border:1px solid red;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#ccc;    
}
```

[Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/3Zv5s/10/)

**UPDATED**

You could set container to `position: absolute;` and make `.mydiv` to `display:table-cell` and `vertical-align:middle`.

HTML -

```
<div id="container"><div class="mydiv">Frameworks and Extensions</div></div>
```

CSS -

```
#container{
    position: absolute;
}

.mydiv{
    width:100px;
    height:70px;
    border:1px solid red;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#ccc;    
}
```

[Try for this](http://jsfiddle.net/3Zv5s/13/)

Comment: display:table-cell doesn't work on absolutely positioned elements

Comment: Yes, I removed "position" property into CSS.

Comment: you are kind of removing part of the functionality then as it says: "My text is placed in position:absolute div."

Comment: Can't we do without adding another div inside or outside?

Comment: @PavanKumar not if you want the div to be absolutely positioned (as stated in your question), if the div doesn't need that style then you can just get rid of the outside div

Answer (score 0):

You could put your text into a table and use `vertical-align`

http://jsfiddle.net/3Zv5s/6/

Comment: it's just a method different from everyone elses

Comment: On the other hand, all browsers will support it!

Comment: @MarcAudet ;) exactly

Comment: seo and accessibility won't though - tables are for tabular data!

Comment: Table data shouldn't be a problem for SEO

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="mydiv">
    <span class="span">Frameworks and Extensions</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.mydiv{display:table-row;}
.span{display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;height:inherit;}
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Zv5s/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of `display: table` and `display: table-cell`.

Change slightly your markup:

```
<div class="mydiv">
    <div>Frameworks and Extensions</div>
</div>
```

And your CSS:

```
.mydiv{
    width:100px;
    height:70px;
    border:1px solid red;
    display: table;
    background-color:#ccc;  
    overflow: hidden;
}

.mydiv div {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3Zv5s/2/

Answer (score 0):

### Option #1 : table-cell

Simplest solution, but **only for IE7+**

```
<div class="mydiv">
    <span>Frameworks and Extensions</span>
</div>
```

```
.mydiv {
    width:100px;
    height:70px;
    border:1px solid red;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#ccc;   

    display: table;
}
.mydiv>span {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle; 
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zessx/3Zv5s/12/)**

### Option #2 : double span

A bit more tricky, but works under IE7

```
<div class="mydiv">
    <span><span>Frameworks and Extensions</span></span>
</div>
```

```
.mydiv {
    width:100px;
    height:70px;
    border:1px solid red;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#ccc;   

    display: block;
    line-height: 65px; /* 70px applied on 1st span */
}
.mydiv>span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle; /* 2nd span centered */
    line-height: 0;
}
.mydiv>span>span {
    line-height: 20px; /* here's the "true" line-height */
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zessx/3Zv5s/9/)**